# Is removing Entity from GetChanges().Insert Legal?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I was wondering if it is a good practice to remove entity from the DataContext.GetChanges.Insert Collection?

Here I explain a bit more.

For some reason, I'm at a point where a row/entity have been inserted in a table and the SubmitChanges have not yet been called, so the Row is in pending insertion state and can be found in the DataContext.GetChanges(). But for some business logic reason I want to prevent that row from been inserted into the Database.

so a though about remove using something like :

```
DataContact.GetChages().Inserted.Remove(myRow);
```

Is this good?

Thanks

Comment: Well after some test I realize that my approach is not feasible, sorry

Comment: using DataContext.MyTable.DeleteOnSubmit(MyUnwantedRow); work well

Comment: You haven't even _tested_ before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not do anything. The ChangeSet that you are operating on is just a snapshot that has no connection back to the DataContext. You can do with it whatever you want, it won't cause the DataContext to behave differently.